How to upgrade wso2 api manager from 4.2.0 to 4.3.0
We are using community edition of WSO2 API Manager,
Is there any clear document that could help us in upgrading API Manager from 4.2.0 to 4.3.0 ?
Currently , we are Not sure how to proceed further on this upgrade
Thanks in Advance!!

APIM 4.2.0 to 4.3.0 will not have a data migration. Since you are using the community edition, the best option would be to compare the database schemas of the two versions and do the necessary changes and move to APIM 4.3.0. Alternatively, you could try to contact WSO2 through the website and get support for migration if needed.
